# Error message in Java after extending JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I'm having trouble with a snippet of code I am working on. I am extending JFrame in a class that contains my main method. I am sort of new to Java (learned it in university, have some practice with it, but still get stuck). I have a return type in my locate method that my IDE, eclipse NEON, is saying convert to COMPONENT. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Board extends JFrame 
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
boolean result;
int counter2;
int counter = 100000;
Point point = new Point(1,2,3); 
int to_be_changed = 100000;
Point[] point2 = new Point[100000];
private int fortree = 0;


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Board bb = new Board();
    int colChange = 1;


        bb.add(1 ,0 ,1);

    new work(bb);               
}
public void add(int xco, int yco, int Colr)
{
    point2[point2.length - counter] = new Point(xco, yco, Colr);
    counter--;
    counter2++;
}

public boolean Filled(int x1, int y1)
{
    int i = 0;

    do{
        if (i > 100000){ i = 0; }
        result = ((point2[i].getPoinx() == x1) && (point2[i].getPointy()== y1));
        i++;
      }while((result == false) && (i != counter2));


    return result;
}

public Point locate(int x1, int y1)
{
    Point backer = new Point(0,0,0);

    for (int j = 0; ((j < point2.length) && (result == false) && (point2[j]) != null); j++ )
    {
        if ((point2[j].getPoinx() == x1) && (point2[j].getPointy() == y1)) 
         {
            backer = point2[j];
            result = true;
         }
    }

    return backer;
}

public void setfortree()
{
    this.fortree++;
}

public int getfortree()
{
    return this.fortree;
}

}

class work
{
    work(Board y)
    {
    Intelligence p = new Intelligence();
    System.out.println(p.tree(0, 0, y, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class contains already a lot of methods. You are overriding an already existing method. One of those methods belongs to the superclass [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#locate(int,%20int)) and has

- as return-type a `Component`.
- same list of parameters (two ints).

  @Deprecated
  public Component locate(int x, int y)

Eclipse knows about this and then reminds you that `locate` needs to return this `Component`. An easy test for this could be the renaming of your method.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `JFrame` and you have a method called `locate` which has the same signature as `Container#locate` method (Hierarchy of `JFrame`: `JFrame > Frame > Window > Container`, so parent class implicitly have a method called `locate`). So you are overriding it but your return type is not matching the `Container#locate`.

You have two alternative to solve it:

1. Change your return type to Component as eclipse advised you.
2. Change the name of your `locate` method to something else if you are not intended to override that method of `Container` class.

Good Luck